# Delete inserted rows after tests are executed in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've made unit tests for my Laravel project, and I have a `setUp` method which looks like this:

```
    public function setUp()
    {   
        parent::setUp();
        $this->user = factory(User::class)->states('admin', 'manager', 'code', 'coordinator')->create();
    }
```

My goal is, to delete this row from my database after the tests are executed. I could delete it in a `tearDown` method, but my question is: Is there a better way to do it, than manually delete it? I mean something like which handles this in the background?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Version `5.6.28`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test should be what you need. Failing that you could always add a `tearDown` method and explicitly delete the row.

Comment: This statement deleted all data from my database before executing my tests. I don't want to delete the existing data, only the inserted ones, after the tests

Comment: It might be an idea to set up a separate db for testing that won't interfere will you main data. Failing that, I would just add a `tearDown` method to the class and then delete the row from in there.

Comment: "_This statement deleted all data from my database before executing my tests_" Which shouldn't matter since you hopefully set up a test database different from your DEV/LIVE database

Comment: Actually I decided to not to use a testing database until now, I know I should. Anyways, I thought that there could be something that I'm missing, but it seems there isn't. I tried the `use DatabaseTransaction` trait also, but it rolled back very quickly, even before I had the chance to work with the inserted data. What does exactly that trait?

Answer (score -14):

You can use this action after testing

```
 DB::statement("TRUNCATE TABLE users;");
```

Comment: If I understand correctly from the documentation, this command will delete all of my data, which I don't want to happen